# Currying addition function in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I wanted to write an `add` function that implemented currying in JavaScript. I welcome criticism and suggestions for improvement.

```
function add(...args1) {
  if(!args1.length) {
    return sum(args1);
  }

  return (...args2) => {
    if(!args2.length) {
      return sum(args1.concat(args2));
    }

    return add.apply(null, args1.concat(args2));        
  };
}

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((p,c) => p+c,0);
}

console.assert(add(1,2)(3)(4)() === 10, '1+2+3+4 should be 10');
```

Comment: Pffff using es6 is cheating! ;-)

Comment: useful Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZLP4qOwY8I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about this part:

```
if(!args1.length) {
  return sum(args1);
}
```

If the array's empty, you could just return zero - no need to call `sum`.

Secondly, you're doubling possible return types for `add`. You either get a new curried function, or you get a number.

This goes for the curried function as well, really, as it too will return either a sum or another function.

So either way, it's kinda tricky. Partial application/currying is kinda difficult if you have something like this, that you can "keep currying" forever.

Anyway, sticking to your current structure, it can be simplified somewhat. Notably, you don't have to create a new closure for each invocation. And you can get rid of the double `!argsN.length` checks and calls to `sum`:

```
function add(...initial) {
  let list = [];

  function adder(...values) {
    if(!values.length) {
      return list.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0);
    }

    list.push(...values);
    return adder;
  }

  return adder(...initial);
}
```

Here, I've named the nested function, so it can return itself. After the initial call to `add`, the nested `adder` function is created, closes over the `list` array, and is invoked. It then either returns the sum or it returns itself. I.e. only one closure is created, and subsequent calls simply update the closed over `list` - or sums it.

`adder` also handles all the input checking etc.. The outer `add` function only exists to create and invoke it.

Also note that I renamed the argument arrays, as `args1` and `args2` really aren't too descriptive. And that the `...`-splat works for both definition and invocation. And, lastly, since it only need to do a sum in 1 place, there's no need for a separate `sum` function.

Comment: Is it a common pattern to move control back and forth between two functions per the code in the question, or is this generally seen as an over-complication?

Comment: @Ben I don't know if it's common enough to be called a "pattern", really. It's a function factory - just a (possibly) recursive one. In and of itself that's probably fine. I mostly changed the structure because it seemed simpler (and removed some repetition) in this particular case. In other cases, the original structure might make more sense